# SIGCHILD signal in java

Tags: java, signals

I create a child process using 'Runtime.getRuntime().exec()' in java and want to detect when child process exits. so i want to know  is there any signal like 'SIGCHILD' in posix?

Answer (score 1):

No, not precisely. You can call `Process.waitFor()` to wait for the process to exit. If you did that from a dedicated thread, however, that would be quite similar to a signal handler. Alternatively, a more expensive method is to poll `Process.exitValue()`, which will throw an exception until the child has actually exited.

Comment: Because i want to call 'exec()' asynchronously, so the 'wait' maybe unsuitable to me.  I just found a package 'sun.misc.Signal' and 'sun.misc.SignalHandler' may help me work around this. A signal handler could created like 'this:Signal.handle(new Signal("INT"), new SignalHandler ()', but it seems java could not support 'sigchild'.

Comment: To "call `exec()` asynchronously", just create a new `Thread` and call `exec()` from that `Thread`. That `Thread` is then free to wait for the process to exit before ending. That's the Java way to do things. And in any case, classes in the `sun.*` hierarchy are implementation-dependent and subject to change -- one should *never* use them in application code. They're there to support the internal implementation of the JVM and the API, and they're not designed with the flexibility, error handling, or stability needed for user access in mind.